# How can i use controllerAs syntax for a directive that has only a link function

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am not able to use controllerAs syntax for directives without a controller added to it and has only link function. In this case I need to write some object names in my template without (.) notation which may get conflicted with parent controller variables. 

 Is there any way already for it?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('exDir',function(){
  return {
    scope: {
        displayName : '=name'
    },
    controllerAs : 'ctrl',
    template : 'Name : <span>{{ctrl.displayName}}</span>'
  }
});

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'Raju';
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller = 'myCtrl'>
          <ex-dir name='name'></ex-dir>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XWuD6FQHwhGJsh3CKU9z) is the plunker.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @zeroflagL, Most of my directives are not having any controller and just have link functions. They have an isolated scope values which will be used in template files. Like in the above example, I can access the isolated scope value in the template like `{{displayName}}` and it will work. But as the best practice, I read that we need to use `controllerAs` syntax everywhere so that we can access scope variables like `{{AliasName.displayName}}`. When I don't have controller attached to directives, how do I follow this best practice in my code?

Comment: @DRB if you want to use controllerAs syntax , you need to declare controller .without that it doesnt have meaning for it